# What's the deal with someone or something?

Tags: meaning

[Supergirl](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7637966/characters/nm2552034)

> Leslie Willis : **So what's the deal with** that beautiful girl? I
> mean, does everyone in the future look like that?

What's the exactly question of "what't the deal with ... "? What does the questioner want to know with the question?

I find [What's the deal](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=What%27s%20the%20deal%20with) on Urban Dict. It says it's a meme, but I'm not sure if this term had existed before the meme got popular.

Comment: It is a vague idiom that has the sense of "there is something i really want to know about" some subject. It usually comes before a specific question. As such, the idiom itself has little direct meaning, but rather creates emphasis ahead of the actual question. In the example, Willis is impressed with the appearance of someone, leading to following question. Without the idiom, we would not know that his emotional response is so strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a vague idiom that has the sense of "there is something I really want to know about" some subject. It usually comes before a specific question. As such, the idiom itself has little direct meaning, but rather creates emphasis ahead of the actual question. In the example, Willis is impressed with the appearance of someone, leading to the following question. Without the idiom, we would not know that his emotional response is so strong.

Answer (score 1):

Another usage of 'what's the deal with' and the similar 'what's up with' or 'what's their deal' forms is one of asking *an implied question*. This method is used very often when the thing being investigated stands out clearly, especially when it might be rude to directly describe it. For example, if Tiffany stormed out of a party crying, you might ask a friend 'What's the deal with Tiffany?', as an indirect but clear way of asking 'Do you know why Tiffany's upset?.'